# implementando onClick

Tags: android

Meu problema é o seguinte:

Tenho um Array de string com o nome frases, onde tenho várias frases.

E gostaria de mostra-las todas no mesmo `TextView` uma a uma cada vez que pressionar o botão "próxima".

Qualquer dica será bem recebida obrigado.

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Para que a comunidade possa te ajudar, é importante que se explique detalhadamente o seu problema, E exiba o que você fez até o momento!

Sugiro que leia os artigos: [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e [como realizar uma pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).    Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá !
Segue um exemplo de como deve ficar seu `OnCLick`:

```
int ponteiro = 0;
private View.OnClickListener nextAction(){
return  new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {      

        // vamos ver se o ponteiro é menor que o tamanho da lista
        // tiramos 1, pois abaixo vamos adicionar mais 1!
        if(ponteiro < (frases.size()-1) ){
        // vamos andar uma posição com o ponteiro
        ponteiro++;
        }else{ 
       // vamos zerar o ponteiro
        ponteiro = 0;
       }
         // Agora vamos mostrar o item da Lista
         meuTextView.setText(frases.get(ponteiro));
};
}
```

Para adicionar a ação em seu botão :

```
botaoProximo.setOnClickListener(nextAction());
```

Comment: fala Thiago Luiz Domacosk, obrigado por tentar ajudar cara, então. declarei meu array assim: String [] frases = getResources().getStringArray (R.array.frases);  porem quando tento usar a combinação frases.size na iteração if o "size " não existe...sabe me dizer porque?

Comment: Tente **length** no lugar de **size()**. A propriedade **length** refere-se ao **String[]**, e o método **size()** e de um **List<String>**

Comment: E ao invés de **frases.get(ponteiro)** use **frases[ponteiro]**

Comment: Vlw Thiago Luiz Domacoski. Deu certo. Obrigado.

Comment: Thiago to tentando implementar o botão "anterior" e fiz assim dentro do metodo:      'if (ponteiro<frases.langth){ ponteiro--;} else {oque coloco aqui? }'  ja tentei de várias maneiras mas não consegui poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Se no próximo vamos para o inicio da lista, no anterior, vamos para o final! Então coloque:  **ponteiro=frases.length**!

Comment: O **if** é diferente no caso do anterior: deve se comparar se ponteiro é maior que zero: if(ponteiro<0){ ponteiro--; }else{ponteiro =frases.length;}

Comment: Boa sua lógica...fiz como explicou mas quando chega na posição 0, ao invés de ir pro fim do array o app trava...onde sera o erro?

Comment: Desculpe, tente assim: if(ponteiro>0) Enquanto for **maior** que zero decrementa, senão volta pro fim

Comment: Não ta dando o erro agora acontece na passagem de 1 pra 0 o app trava

Comment: Qual erro ele mostra?

Comment: Tente: ponteiro= frases.length-1;

Comment: Agora deu certo Thiago, so faltava "frases.length-1

Comment: Obrigado Thiago